# When a socket error occur, how to get its errorcode from the exception?

Tags: python, sockets, exception, error-handling, error-code

Codes like this:

```
import socket, sys

try:
    address = ('127.0.0.1', 31500)  
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
    s.connect(address)  
except Exception:
    errType, errValue, errTraceback = sys.exc_info()
    # or
    # handle the Exception it throw out ?
```

What I want to get is the errcode like `10060` which means `connection time out`, thanks for any help :)

Comment: what is your Python version? Why do you use `sys.exc_info()` instead of for example `except socket.timeout:` for the timeout error (note: `.errno is None` in this case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
except EnvironmentError as e:
    print e.errno
```

Comment: @nneonneo Maybe this is not I want, when I try to connect to a socket, e.strerror is 'Connection Refused' which should has the errorcode '10061', but e.errno shows '111', Why?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Errno 111 is ECONNREFUSED on Linux. Error numbers are OS-specific; you'd only see 10061 if you were running on Windows.

Comment: @Coaku (+1, this is the way to go.) If you are trying to only catch specific situations, you can use the [errno module](http://docs.python.org/library/errno.html#module-errno) to avoid working directly with error numbers.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Makes sense, since it isn't necessarily tied to a particular errno. But, luckily, you can deal with it separately with a `except socket.timeout` above the `except EnvironmentError`.

Comment: @nneonneo HA, thanks, but when I try to connect to a wrong domain which e.errno whould be negtive number like '-5', shouldn't the errno between 0~256 ?

Comment: @nneonneo Is there another better way to handle all socket's exceptions while can get all exact errnos? My program need this. :)

Comment: @Coaku no, none that I know of anyways.  Not all paths are the result of system calls, which is what generally sets errno.  Things happen for other reasons.  Dealing with all the ways that things fail is the one of the more difficult parts of writing software, unfortunately.